# Xcode change to default scope

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.2

How to revert back to default project scope [image: default scope] after using Custom Scopes in Xcode. 
I tried below approach,

1. Selected Scope Option [image: scope option] below search field
2. Tapped on root file, which is `.xcodeproject`.

This searches text inside .xcodeproject. I was expecting to search in entire project.

**Trying to get**

[image: required]

**But now it is like**

[image: problem]

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all the custom scopes showed me the default scope which i was looking for.

Thanks!